# Where in a theme is the selection box color for the desktop for Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, themes, gnome-shell, colors, desktop-icons

On the desktop, the selection box color is blue, as seen here.

[image: The selection box is blue on the desktop.]

How can I change this color? I looked through the CSS, but didn't have any keywords or color codes I could explicitly search for. How do you change this color, or what is something I can use to change it? The theme is Mojave-dark from [McMojave](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1275087/).

Comment: I can't get a link to the specific download from gnome-look, so here's a [reupload](https://gofile.io/d/ASrRUB). If you want a different file host I can try and upload it to a different place as well @PRATAP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have installed the theme `Mojave-dark` in local folder
`$HOME/.themes/`

open the file gtk.css and edit it..

```
gedit $HOME/.themes/Mojave-dark/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
```

and add the below content to it..

```
XfdesktopIconView.view .rubberband, .content-view rubberband, treeview.view rubberband, flowbox rubberband,
rubberband,
.rubberband {
  border: 1px solid #113edc;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Change the color "red" to any valid color..

But the color red is applied with some opacity.. This is because of the configuration in gnome-shell-extension `desktop-icons`

If you need further customization to avoid the opacity, you need to dig the said extension files..

[image]